# Include some jquery code in another without copying and pasting

Tags: jquery

I am trying to avoid copying and pasting here. I have a jquery which is a  .`submit` and an ajax which is. `blur`. The `submit` has some `var` and other bits of code I want to include in the `blur` function but I want to avoid a copy and paste issues how can I do this please.

*submit*

```
  $('#guess').submit(function() {
```

// this code below is want I need to include in the `blur` function

```
        var buttonWidth=$('#guess button').width();
        var buttonCopy = $('#guessbutton').html(),
        errorGuess = $('#guess button').data('error-guess'),
        sendGuess = $('#guess button').data('send-guess'),
        okGuess= $('#guess button').data('ok-guess'),
        hasError = false;
     }
```

*blur*

```
$('#number').blur(function() {
  var number = $(this).val();
```

//I need to include the code from `submit` here but I dont want to copy and paste

```
 }
```

p.s. the jquery and ajax are both in one file.

please advise

Comment: Then try writing Functions. And call that fn anywhere like: `var a = function() {...code...}; and call the fn a()`. Simple

Comment: So wrap relevant code in function and call function in both handlers

Comment: @A.Wolff I did but I still needed to duplicate `var buttonWidth=$('#contact-form button').width();
  
  var buttonCopy = $('#contact-form button').html(),` as it wasn't getting including when i call it in other function

Comment: @user3057514 you can wrap function inside another function and call function with parameter. There are many ways you can handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question, put your code in a seperate function like this:

```
    function yourName (){
      var buttonWidth=$('#guess button').width();
      var buttonCopy = $('#guessbutton').html(),
      errorGuess = $('#guess button').data('error-guess'),
      sendGuess = $('#guess button').data('send-guess'),
      okGuess= $('#guess button').data('ok-guess'),
      hasError = false;
    }
```

then call your functions ...

```
    $('#guess').submit(function() {
       yourName();
    }

    $('#number').blur(function() {
      var number = $(this).val();
      yourName();
    }
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Just create a wrapper function that encapsulates all the functionality you require that you would otherwise duplicate.

```
//Might not be valid syntax, my javascript is a bit rusty as I haven't done any in a few months. But it gives you the idea.
function wrapper(){
        var buttonWidth=$('#guess button').width();
        var buttonCopy = $('#guessbutton').html(),
        errorGuess = $('#guess button').data('error-guess'),
        sendGuess = $('#guess button').data('send-guess'),
        okGuess= $('#guess button').data('ok-guess'),
        hasError = false;
}
```

Comment: I ain't into javascript that much but its one of the things i need to spend sometime learning.

Comment: Well this pattern is not just for javascript it applies across pretty much all languages. Code reuse is an extremely important concept and there are a myriad of ways of doing it. Software design patterns are a good thing to look at if you want to learn more about code reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$('#guess').on('validate', function() {
    var buttonWidth=$('#guess button').width();
    var buttonCopy = $('#guessbutton').html(),
    errorGuess = $('#guess button').data('error-guess'),
    sendGuess = $('#guess button').data('send-guess'),
    okGuess= $('#guess button').data('ok-guess'),
    hasError = false;
}
$('#guess').submit(function() {
    $(this).trigger('validate');
});

$('#number').blur(function() {
    var number = $(this).val();
    $('#guess').trigger('validate');
});
```

Comment: what I realized in all answers was that I still needed to duplicate `var buttonWidth=$('#contact-form button').width();
  
  var buttonCopy = $('#contact-form button').html(),` because it doesn't get including in the `submit` and `blur` function.